# Which statically typed languages support intersection types for function return values?

Tags: language-agnostic, type-systems, return-type

> **Initial note:**
>
> This question got closed after several edits because I lacked the proper terminology to state accurately what I was looking for. Sam Tobin-Hochstadt then posted a comment which made me recognise exactly what that was: programming languages that support intersection types for function return values.
>
> Now that the question has been re-opened, I've decided to improve it by rewriting it in a (hopefully) more precise manner. Therefore, some answers and comments below might no longer make sense because they refer to previous edits. (Please see the question's edit history in such cases.)

Are there any popular statically & strongly typed programming languages (such as Haskell, generic Java, C#, F#, etc.) that support [intersection types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Intersection_types) for function return values? If so, which, and how?

(If I'm honest, I would really love to see someone demonstrate a way how to express intersection types in a mainstream language such as C# or Java.)

I'll give a quick example of what intersection types might look like, using some pseudocode similar to C#:

```
interface IX { … }
interface IY { … }
interface IB { … }

class A : IX, IY { … }
class B : IX, IY, IB { … }

T fn()  where T : IX, IY
{
    return … ? new A()  
             : new B();
}
```

That is, the function `fn` returns an instance of some type `T`, of which the caller knows only that it implements interfaces `IX` and `IY`. (That is, unlike with generics, the caller doesn't get to choose the concrete type of `T` — the function does. From this I would suppose that `T` is in fact not a universal type, but an existential type.)

**P.S.:** I'm aware that one could simply define a `interface IXY : IX, IY` and change the return type of `fn` to `IXY`. However, that is not really the same thing, because often you cannot bolt on an additional interface `IXY` to a previously defined type `A` which only implements `IX` and `IY` separately.

---

> <sub>**Footnote: Some resources about intersection types:**</sub>
>
> <sub>Wikipedia article for *"Type system"* has a [subsection about intersection types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Intersection_types).</sub>
>
> <sub>Report by Benjamin C. Pierce (1991), [*"Programming With Intersection Types, Union Types, and Polymorphism"*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.39.8007)</sub>
>
> <sub>David P. Cunningham (2005), [*"Intersection types in practice"*](http://spark.woaf.net/MAC/dc04ISOReportTerm1.pdf), which contains a case study about the Forsythe language, which is mentioned in the Wikipedia article.</sub>
>
> <sub>A Stack Overflow question, [*"Union types and intersection types"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5653678/240733) which got several good answers, among them [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5987198/240733) which gives a pseudocode example of intersection types similar to mine above.</sub>

Comment: How is this ambiguous? `T` defines a type, even if it's just defined within the function declaration as "some type that extends/implements `IX` and `IY`". The fact that the *actual* return value is a special case of that (`A` or `B` respectively) isn't anything special here, you could just as well achieve that by using `Object` instead of `T`.

Comment: Ruby allows you to return whatever you want from a function. Same for other dynamic languages.

Comment: I've updated my answer. @Joachim: I'm aware that the term "ambigous" doesn't capture the concept in question very accurately, thus the example to clarify the intended meaning.

Comment: @thorsten: I forgot to mention that I'm interested in strongly-typed languages, since otherwise the answer to this question would be very trivial. Question updated.

Comment: Ad P.S.: ... which changes your question to "which language allows treating type `T` as interface `I` when it implements all methods of the interface, but did not declare that interface".

Comment: so you want a list of languages that allow duck typing in some way?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't confuse "strong" typing with "static" typing? "strong" typing means the language knows what type things are, "weak" typing means it does not. So C is weakly typed, because you cast pointers to incompatible types all the time there, while perl, python, ruby and java are all strongly typed, because an object always stays of the type it was created as there.

Comment: OK... let's settle on strong, static typing since I definitely don't want to include dynamic typing, duck-typing, or completely untyped languages. Thanks for reminding me that "strong typing" is somewhat ambigious, too.

Comment: It was a mistake to close this question, because there's a precise answer, which is *union types*.  Union types are available in languages such as (Typed Racket)[http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/].

Comment: @Sam, thank you for a very valuable hint: I wasn't looking for the union types you mention, but for their counterpart: [**intersection types**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Intersection_types). Now that I know the proper term, I'm confident that I'll find an answer to my question. I'd accept your comment as an answer if that were possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scala has full intersection types built into the language:

```
trait IX {...}
trait IY {...}
trait IB {...}

class A() extends IX with IY {...}

class B() extends IX with IY with IB {...}

def fn(): IX with IY = if (...) new A() else new B()
```

Comment: dotty based scala would have true intersection types, but not for current/former scala.

Answer (score 10):

In fact, the obvious answer is: Java

Whilst it may surprise you to learn that Java supports intersection types ... it does indeed through the "&" type bound operator.  For example:

```
<T extends IX & IY> T f() { ... }
```

See [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) on multiple type bounds in Java, and [also this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/TypeVariable.html) from the Java API.

Comment: Will that work if you don't know the type at compile time? I.e. can one write `<T extends IX & IY> T f() { if(condition) return new A(); else return new B(); }`. And how do you call the function in such case? Neither A nor B can appear at the call site, because you don't know which one you'll get.

Comment: Yes, you're right --- its not equivalent to the original example given since you do need to provide a concrete type.  If we could use wildcards with intersection bounds, then we'd have it.  Seems like we can't ... and I don't really know why not (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643241/why-cant-you-have-multiple-interfaces-in-a-bounded-wildcard-generic)).  But, still Java does have intersection types of a sort ...

Comment: I feel disappointed that I somehow never learned about intersection types in the 10 years I did Java.  Now that I use the all the time with Flowtype I thought they were the biggest missing feature in Java, only to find I had never even once seen them in the wild.  People are seriously underutilizing them.  I think if they were better known, then dependency injection frameworks like Spring would have never become so popular.

Answer (score 8):

#### Original question asked for "ambiguous type". For that the answer was:

Ambiguous type, obviously none. The caller needs to know what they'll get, so it's isn't possible. All any language can return is either base type, interface (possibly auto-generated as in intersection type) or dynamic type (and dynamic type is basically just type with by-name call, get and set methods).

#### Inferred interface:

So basically you want it to return an interface `IXY` that derives `IX` *and* `IY` though that interface was not declared in either `A` or `B`, possibly because wasn't declared when those types were defined. In that case:

- Any that is dynamically typed, obviously.
- I don't remember any statically typed mainstream language would be able to generate the interface (it is the **union** type of `A` and `B` or intersection type of `IX` and `IY`) itself.
- [GO](http://golang.org/), because it's classes implement interface if they have the correct methods, without ever declaring them. So you just declare an interface that derives the two there and return it.
- Obviously any other language where type can be defined to implement interface outside of definition of that type, but I don't think I remember any other than GO.
- It's not possible in any type where implementing an interface has to be defined in the type definition itself. You can however work around in most of them by defining wrapper that implements the two interfaces and delegates all methods to a wrapped object.

**P.S.** A *strongly* typed language is one in which an object of given type can't be treated as object of another type, while *weakly* typed language is one that has a reinterpret cast. Thus *all dynamically typed languages are strongly typed*, while weakly typed languages are assembly, C and C++, all three being typed *statically*.

Comment: This is not correct there is nothing ambiguous about the type.  A language can return so-called "intersection types" --- it's just that few if any mainstream languages do so.

Comment: @redjamjar: The question had different wording when I answered it and asked for "ambiguous type". That's why it starts with that. The question was significantly rewritten since. I'll expand the answer to mention both the original and the current wording.

Comment: sorry, I missed that obviously!

Comment: +1 for mentioning Golang, which is probably the best example of a common language that allows this, even if the way to do it is a little circuitous.

Answer (score 3):

[The Go Programming Language](http://golang.org/) *kind of* has this, but only for interface types.

In Go any type for which the correct methods are defined automatically implements an interface, so the objection in your P.S. doesn't apply. In other words, just create an interface that has all the operations of the interface types to be combined (for which there's a simple syntax) and it all Just Works.

An example:

```cs
package intersection

type (
    // The first component type.
    A interface {
        foo() int
    }
    // The second component type.
    B interface {
        bar()
    }

    // The intersection type.
    Intersection interface {
        A
        B
    }
)

// Function accepting an intersection type
func frob(x Intersection) {
    // You can directly call methods defined by A or B on Intersection.
    x.foo()
    x.bar()

    // Conversions work too.
    var a A = x
    var b B = x
    a.foo()
    b.bar()
}

// Syntax for a function returning an intersection type:
// (using an inline type definition to be closer to your suggested syntax)
func frob2() interface { A; B } {
    // return something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to do what you want by using a bounded existential type, which can be encoded in any language with generics and bounded polymorphism, e.g. C#.

The return type will be something like (in psuedo code)

`IAB = exists T. T where T : IA, IB`

or in C#:

```
interface IAB<IA, IB>
{
    R Apply<R>(IABFunc<R, IA, IB> f);
}

interface IABFunc<R, IA, IB>
{
    R Apply<T>(T t) where T : IA, IB;
}

class DefaultIAB<T, IA, IB> : IAB<IA, IB> where T : IA, IB 
{
    readonly T t;

    ...

    public R Apply<R>(IABFunc<R, IA, IB> f) {
        return f.Apply<T>(t);
    }
}
```

Note: I haven't tested this.

The point is that `IAB` has to be able to apply an IABFunc for any return type `R`, and an `IABFunc` has to be able to work on any `T` which subtypes both `IA` and `IB`.

The intent of `DefaultIAB` is just to wrap an existing `T` which subtypes `IA` and `IB`. Note that this is different from your `IAB : IA, IB` in that `DefaultIAB` can always be added to an existing `T` later on.

References:

- [Existential types in C#](http://blog.functorial.com/posts/2010-12-04-Existential-Types.html)

Comment: The approach works if one adds a generic object-wrapper type with parameters T, IA , IB, with T constrained to the interfaces, which encapsulates a reference of type T and allows `Apply` to be invoked upon it.  The big problem is that there's no way to use an anonymous function to implement an interface, so constructs like that end up being a real pain to use.

Answer (score 3):

[Ceylon](http://ceylon-lang.org) has full support for first-class union and [intersection types](http://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.1/tour/types/#intersection_types).

You write a union type as `X | Y` and an intersection type as `X & Y`.

Even better, Ceylon features a lot of sophisticated reasoning about these types, including:

- *principal instantiations:* for example, `Consumer<X>&Consumer<Y>` is  the same type as `Consumer<X|Y>` if `Consumer` is contravariant in `X`, and
- *disjointness:* for example, `Object&Null` is the same type as `Nothing`, the bottom type.

Answer (score 3):

[TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org) is another typed language that supports intersection types `T & U` (along with union types `T | U`). Here's an example cited from [their documentation page about advanced types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

> ```
> function extend<T, U>(first: T, second: U): T & U {
>     let result = <T & U>{};
>     for (let id in first) {
>         (<any>result)[id] = (<any>first)[id];
>     }
>     for (let id in second) {
>         if (!result.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
>             (<any>result)[id] = (<any>second)[id];
>         }
>     }
>     return result;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

While Rust does not have the traditional OOP notion of inheritance, it does have a notion of traits and trait objects. Object-safe traits perform roughly the same role as interfaces, and trait objects express most of the same affordances as interface-typed objects in OOP languages like C# and Java.

Rust lets you express a trait object for any [object-safe trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety), and a new trait can be defined that represents an arbitrary intersection of traits, then automatically implemented for all implementors of the constituent traits. This new trait will be object-safe if its supertraits are. This means that it is possible to return a trait object for an arbitrary intersection of object-safe traits, and you [*can* bolt-on the new trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/implementations.html#orphan-rules) to an externally-defined type.

Unfortunately, this object of an intersection of traits can't be expressed simply as `dyn X + Y`*, and needs the explicit boilerplate of a subtrait and blanket implementation. See the RFC for [Trait objects for multiple traits](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/2035).

```rust
fn returns_intersection(which: bool) -> Box<dyn XY> {
    if (which) {
        Box::new(A{ … })
    } else {
        Box::new(B{ … })
    }
}

trait X { … }
trait Y { … }
trait Z { … }

trait XY: X + Y {}
impl<T: X + Y> XY for T {}

struct A { … };

impl X for A { … }
impl Y for A { … }

struct B { … };

impl X for B { … }
impl Y for B { … }
impl Z for B { … }
```

*except under [limited](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error_codes/E0225.html) [circumstances](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/32220)

Answer (score 0):

C++ functions all have a fixed return type, but if they return pointers the pointers can, with restrictions, point to different types.

Example:

```
class Base {};
class Derived1: public Base {};
class Derived2: public Base{};

Base * function(int derived_type)
{
    if (derived_type == 1)
        return new Derived1;
    else
        return new Derived2;
}
```

The behavior of the returned pointer will depend on what `virtual` functions are defined, and you can do a checked downcast with, say,

`Base * foo = function(...);dynamic_cast<Derived1>(foo)`.

That's how polymorphism works in C++.

Comment: And of course one can use an `any` or a `variant` type, like the templates boost provides. Thus, the restriction doesn't stay.

Comment: This isn't quite what the question was asking, though, which was for a way to specify that the return type extends two identified superclasses at the same time, i.e. `class Base1{}; class Base2{}; class Derived1 : public Base1, public Base2 {}; class Derived2 : public Base1, public Base2 {}`... now what type can we specify that allows returning either `Derived1` or `Derived2` but neither `Base1` nor `Base2` directly?

Answer (score -2):

Python

It's very, very strongly typed.

But the type is not declared when a function is created, so the returned objects are "ambiguous".

In your specific question, a better term might be "Polymorphic".  That's the common use case in Python is to return variant types which implement a common interface.

```
def some_function( selector, *args, **kw ):
    if selector == 'this':
        return This( *args, **kw )
    else:
        return That( *args, **kw )
```

Since Python is strongly typed, the resulting object will be an instance of `This` or `That` and cannot (easily) be coerced or cast to another type of object.

Comment: This is quite misleading; while the type of an object is pretty much immutable, values can be converted between types quite easily.   To str, for example, trivially.

Comment: @JamesYoungman: What?  That's true for all languages.  All languages I've ever seen have to_string conversions left, right and center.  I don't get your comment at all.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: I was trying to understand what you meant by "Python is strongly typed".   Perhaps I misunderstood what you meant by "strongly typed".   Frankly Python has few of the characteristics I would associate with strongly typed languages.   For example, it accepts programs in which a function's return type is not compatible with the caller's use of the value.   For example, "x, y = F(z)" where F() returns (z,z,z).

Comment: The type of a Python object cannot (without serious magic) be changed.  There is no "cast" operator as there is with Java and C++.  That makes each object strongly typed.  Variable names and function names have no type binding, but the objects themselves are strongly typed.  The key concept here is not the presence of declarations.  The key concept is the available of cast operators.  Also note that this appears to me to be factual; moderators may dispute that, however.

Comment: C and C++ cast operations don't change the type of their operand either.

Comment: @JamesYoungman: I guess I was wrong.  They seem to reinterpret the object's sequence of bytes as if it's a new type of data, changing the type rules, methods and interpretation of the bytes.  That was my understanding.  What really happens if that's not what's happening?

Comment: The operand is not modified.   Casts cannot be lvalues.

Comment: @JamesYoungman: Are you telling me that a C++ cast does not reinterpret the bytes as if they were a new class?  If that's not what happens, can you describe what **does** happen?

Comment: The salient point is that a cast expression produces an rvalue of the specified type.   Not an lvalue.   So for example you can't assign to the result of a cast. The type of the underlying object isn't really changed.

Comment: The value of the new type is -- effectively -- the same bytes with a radically new type.  Something that cannot be done in Python at all, because Python is more strongly-typed than C++.  That is my salient point.

Comment: @JamesYoungman: But a dereference of reinterpret-casted pointer produces an LVALUE. The type of the underlying object is changed at that point.

Comment: @JamesYoungman: Or rather there never was any. In C++ a pointer points to memory that you happen to be treating as some particular type, but the memory does not inherently have it. You can treat it as different type at your discretion, though it's not defined what you'll get in most cases. But not in all, converting between arbitrary objects and bytes is (implementation) defined.

Comment: @JamesYoungman In Python variables do not have types, values have types.  In JavaScript, `2 + '2'` is `'22'`, but in Python it results in a `TypeError`.  That's why Python is still "strongly typed".